# Python regex. How to exclude question mark from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I need to exclude a question mark from a string using the exclusion of that character, but I still get some undesired results. I have to get any link (as text) that doesn't have a question mark, for example, I have to exclude an URL like:

> https://www.example.com/?var=yes

and get any other text (I've already selected which of them are HTTP links, I need those that have /l/ in the middle but without "?").

I tried:

```
re.compile("(/l/){1}[^\?]*")
```

or

```
re.compile("(/l/){1}[^\?]")
```

but I still get some texts with "?".

I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```py
re.compile(r"^[^?]*/l/[^?]*$")
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/73uLK0/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^?]*                    any character except: '?' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /l/                      '/l/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^?]*                    any character except: '?' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern: `^(?!.*\?).*`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCJffq/1)

Comment: Thank you @alireza! Just had to add /l/, but I could manage to make this work.